# Creating a ToolBar in pygame window

Tags: python, pygame, toolbar, pgu

How to Create a toolbar in pygame? I made an initial search regarding this... and got to know about it from http://en.flossmanuals.net/make-your-own-sugar-activities/making-activities-using-pygame/ ... But gi.repository is not working in windows(which i am currently working on). Is there any other library in python which works in windows too so that I can add.. I am actually developing GUI (broadly can be explained similar to as images from a folder keep on scrolling to the right in pygame window and also there is pan n zoom feature implemented.). I just want to have a **"TOOL BAR"** in that pygame window and with two buttons to pause and start the scrolling.

Comment: There is no toolbar in pygame. You have to create your own.

Comment: This example use `PyGTK` - did you install it ? And `GTK` too ?

Comment: This is an inadvertently vague question, because as @furas said, you will have to make your own toolbar in pygame, look up a tutorial :)

Comment: @Tehsmeely ... yeah it might be vague question ... and i was just curious to know about any GUI library other than tkinter and pgu that can be used along with pygame ...

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure, I just make stuff myself. I tried using wxPython to have a separate toolbar window for a map editor ... and oh what a mess it was!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, taking the comments in regard (i.e. you have to make it yourself in pygame), I've got nothing better to do with myself so I'll outline how you can do it.

Defining toolbar as a class, you can fit this to the top of your window and let it deal with the buttons:

```
class Toolbar:
    def __init__(self, width, height): #And other customisation options
        self.image = pygame.Surface(width, height)
        self.image.fill(colour)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (0,0)
        self.leftbutton = ButtonClass(args)
        self.rightbutton = ButtonClass(args)

    def update(self):
        self.leftbutton.hover() #to animate an effect if the mouse hovers over
        self.rightbutton.hover()

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.leftbutton.draw(), self.leftbutton.getRect())
        screen.blit(self.rightbutton.draw(), self.rightbutton.getRect())

    def click(pos):
        if self.leftbutton.getRect().collidepoint(pos):
            self.leftbutton.click()

        if self.rightbutton.getRect().collidepoint(pos):
            self.rightbutton.click()
```

This requires a buttonclass that you can make yourself, but you can also check out the module available for my website (its what i had in mind for the method calls) http://tarqnet.sytes.net/projects/project-Pygame.html

From here, instanciate your toolbar and handle it in your main loop:

```
toolbar = Toolbar(screen_width, 80)

while True:
    toolbar.update()
    toolbar.draw(screen)

    #Other stuff
    ## Events:
    ## on left click call toolbar.click(pos)
```

Comment: Cheers, bro :D The site needs updating too, got a lot more to put up